# How do I prove it formally?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$ and $g(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k z^k$ are two power series whose radii of convergence are $1$. Let the product of $f.g$ has a power series representation $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k z^k$ on the open disk. Is the statement true or false?

My attempt:-

I took $a_k=1$ and $b_k=1$ , By Cauchy's product $c_k=k+1$. $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k z^k$. So, it is convergence in the unit disk. The statement is true. How do I prove it formally?

Comment: Please write an *informative* title that will help others find this problem and solution.

Comment: Product of two analytic functions on the open  unit disk is analytic and hence it has  a power series representation in that disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula implies $\lim \sup_{k\to \infty}|a_k|^{1/k}\le 1\ge \lim \sup_{k\to \infty}|b_k|^{1/k}.$

For $r>0$ let $S(r)=\{0\}\cup \{k>0: |a_k|^{1/k}\ge 1+r \lor |b_k|^{1/k}\ge 1+r\}.$ Then $S(r)$ is finite. Let $M(r)=\max S(r).$ Let $P(r)=\max \{\max \{|a_k|,|b_k|\}: k\le M(r)\}.$

Let $c_k=\sum_{i=0}^k a_i b_{k-j}.$

Given $r>0,$ consider any $k$ large enough that $k>3M(r)$ and $(1+r)^k>P(r).$ If $i+j=k$ then

......(I). If  $M(r)< i<k-M(r)$  then $j>M(r)$ so $|a_ib_j|<(1+r)^i(1+r)^j=(1+r)^k<(1+r)^{2k}.$

.....(II). If $i\le M(r)$ then $j>M(r)$ so $|a_ib_j|\le P(r)(1+r)^j<(1+r)^k(1+r)^j\le (1+r)^{2k}.$

....(III). If $i\ge k-M(r)$ then $j<M(r)<i$ so $|a_ib_j|\le (1+r)^iP(r)<(1+r)^i(1+r)^k\le(1+r)^{2k}.$

So for all sufficiently large $k$ we have $|c_k|^{1/k}\le (\,\sum_{i=0}^k|a_ib_{k-j}|\,)^{1/k}\le$ $ (\,\sum_{i=0}^k(1+r)^{2k}\,)^{1/k}=$ $=(1+r)^2(1+k)^{1/k}.$

Since $\lim_{k\to \infty}(1+k)^{1/k}=1,$ we infer that $\lim \sup_{k\to \infty}|c_k|^{1/k}\le (1+r)^2 $ for every $r>0,$ and hence $\lim \sup_{k\to \infty}|c_k|^{1/k}\le 1.$ The C-H Radius Formula then implies that $\sum_kc_kx^k$ converges whenever $|x|<1.$

Comment: If $R>0,$ and if $\sum_ka_jx^k$ and $\sum_k b_kx^k$ both converge whenever $|x|<R,$ let $x=x'/R$ and $a'_k=a_kR^k$ and $b'_k=b_kR^k$ and  let $c'_k=\sum_{i=0}^ka'_ib'_{k-i}.$ Then $\sum_kc_k x^k=\sum_kc'_kx'^k $ converges whenever $|x'|<1,$ i.e. whenever $|x|<R.$